# Flyway 2 different migrations

Tags: database, database-migration, flyway

Just picked up a project that is using Flyway to rebuild the database. Can't really change the tool without picking a fight with all other devs in the project that have been here much longer.

When I call Flyway Migrate it will rebuild the database - so far so good.

However, I am trying to find a way to have a command that will run one extra script on that database - a script that will populate the base for testing.

For obvious reasons I can't simply stick the scrip on the SQL folder of flyway else ever Migrate will have test data. I need a second command ( or a subset of the migrate ) that can run that extra script.

Halp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same technique as described here to add a separate location to scan for scripts that will only be used in certain environments (like dev & test): https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#db-specific-sql